# Calculating residual in a system based on parity space approach

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I am reading the book Model-Based Fault Diagnosis Techniques, where the chapter on Residual Generation Methods has a section on the Parity Space Approach.

Here, it is said that residual $r(k)=(y_s(k) −H_{u,s}u_s(k))=(H_{o,s}x(k −s))$.

Where $y_s(k)$ and $u_s(k)$ are the representation of present and past outputs and inputs, respectively, $H_{o,s}$ and $H_{u,s}$ is a composite of system matrices $A, B, C, D$ and $x(k −s)$ is the state at $k-s$.

This implies that the output of the residual generator $\hat{y_s}(k)$ is $H_{u,s}u_{s}(k)$. But why is it so?

On the other hand, when we calculate residual $r(k)$ in the case of a system with faults and disturbances, the $H_{o,s}x(k −s)$ term disappears for some reason, and we are left with only $H_{f,s}f_s(k) + H_{d,s}d_s(k)$. Why does it disappear?